# How are gimp c output files used?

Tags: c, header, gimp

Gimp exports images to .c, and the output looks like this. Can someone give me an example of how I might use this to generate an image on screen, or a context to how it might be used?

```
/* GIMP RGBA C-Source image dump (Cassandra.c) */

static const struct {
  guint      width;
  guint      height;
  guint      bytes_per_pixel; /* 2:RGB16, 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */ 
  guint8     pixel_data[300 * 549 * 4 + 1];
} gimp_image = {
  300, 549, 4,
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377"
...
,};
```

Comment: It's just raw image data in a specific format, you can load it in a GUI Toolkit widget if it supports the format, or you can load it in any imaging library, for examlple *cairo* or you can encode it and save it to a file. It's raw image data with a format, so you can do pretty much anything you want with it.

Comment: It's mainly used when the image have to be embedded into program code. For example, the linux boot logo is coded into a C file which is part of the kernel.